# How to find a point in a line in java?

Tags: java, android, math, geometry

I am trying to do some experiments with path. I have two points (x0,y0) and (x2,y2). Now I have to find a point (x1,y1) that should be some distance from the final point (x2,y2).

For example
Start Point (0,0) End Point (0,5)
Point i want to find is (0,2)

[image]

Comment: try y=mx + c formule

Comment: This is really a high-school geometry algorithms question, not a Java question.  Calculate the overall length, then calculate the intermediate point as a fraction of it - proportionality says once you have the length on the diagonal then you can use fractions on the axis differences independently, rather than the diagonal.

Comment: i am so weak with mathematics. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: What do you mean some distance? Any point on the segment?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi yes

Comment: The midpoint formula would give you the center of the points. The distance formula gives you the distance. Since you have the distance, you can rework some variables and fractions around to get any point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a line between

[image]

The point at distance `d` from the *first* point, (positive) in the direction of the *second* point, is given by:

[image]

Where `L` is the distance between the two points defining the line:

[image]

(For your case just take `L - d` instead of `d`)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the two points define two rectangle triangles. The bigger triangle has sides with sizes x1, y1. the smaller has sides of sizes xt, yt.

1) Now apply [Pythagoras' Theorem](http://www.cimt.plymouth.ac.uk/projects/mepres/book8/bk8i3/bk8_3i2.htm) two calculate the bigger hypotenuse, h, using the equation h^2 = x1^2 + y1^2;  (where h^2 means h power of two)

2) the difference ( h - the distance) is the hypotenuse of the smaller triangle. let's call it ht.

3) Calculate xt and yt as directly proportional to hypot bigger/hypot smaller.
x1/xt = h/ht 
y1/yt = h/ht

Answer (score 0):

```
/* I used user3235832 formula and write this code and its solve my problem.
Code in java.
sourcePoint(x,y);
destinationPoint(w,h);*/
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
double l = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((w - x), 2) + Math.pow((h - y), 2));
double d = l / 10;//you can use your own value for d.
int newX = (int) (w + (((x - w) / (l) * d)));
int newy = (int) (h + (((y - h) / (l) * d)));
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
/* if you use like me Graphic2D and use g2d.fillOval() function for draw a oval 
on the line you need line slop. code for this: */
double m = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;//line slop
if (w - x != 0) {
    m = (h - y) / (w - x);
}
int r = 6;//size of Oval
if (m == 0) {
    g2d.fillOval(newX, (newy - (r/2)), r, r);
} else if (m == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
    g2d.fillOval((newX - (r/2)), newy, r, r);
} else if (m < 0) {
    g2d.fillOval((newX - (r/2)), (newy - (r/2)), r, r);
} else {
    g2d.fillOval(newX, newy, r, r);
}
```